# Does Reg-Free COM work with Interop?

Tags: .net, com, interop, regfreecom

What is the consensus here?

I have a VB6 app using Interop to utilise .NET assemblies.  Could I use Reg-Free COM to 'register' the .NET assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. First you create & embed the .NET assembly manifest (the one containing `assemblyIdentity`) then in the VB6 exe manifest you "reference" it with `dependentAssembly` tag.

[Unattended MMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ummm/) generates (and embeds) both manifests.